How to fix error data table 'columns.isNotEmpty': is not true
I am using flutter datatable.
I am using List<DataColumn> and List<DataRow>.
After I click a button, I need to see the table populated.
I am getting the error during runtime: 'columns.isNotEmpty' is not true
I cannot find the source of the error.
Please advise how to fix the error.
Thank You,
This is my code:
class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<DataColumn> myDataColumnList = [];
  List<DataRow> myDataRowList = [];
  int i = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  addToList(){
   setState(() {
     myDataColumnList.add(DataColumn(label: Text('Column Label: '+i.toString())));
     myDataRowList.add(DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[DataCell(placeholder: true,Text('x1: '+i.toString())),DataCell(placeholder: true,Text('x2: '+i.toString()))]));
     i = i + 1;
   });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        body: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext ctx, BoxConstraints constraints) {
              return Container(child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextButton(onPressed: addToList, child: const Text('addToList')),
                  Table(children: [TableRow(children: <Widget>[ListView.builder(shrinkWrap: true,itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return DataTable(columns: myDataColumnList, rows: myDataRowList);
                  },)])]),],),),);
            })));
  }
}


Your lists are empty on the first build.  You can't have an empty data table, apparently.  Remove the table until you have rows.

Add this condition to avoid the error the first time you run the app.
if (myDataColumnList.isNotEmpty)
  Table(children: [
   ....
   ]),


Remove updating myDataColumnList in setState method,
addToList() {
    setState(() {
      // myDataColumnList
      //     .add(DataColumn(label: Text('Column Label: ' + i.toString())));
      myDataRowList.add(DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(placeholder: true, Text('x1: ' + i.toString())),
        DataCell(placeholder: true, Text('x2: ' + i.toString()))
      ]));
      i = i + 1;
    });   
}

Instead, you can initialize your myDataColumnList in initstate
Try something like:
return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextButton(onPressed: addToList, child: const Text('addToList')),
          DataTable(
            columns: [
              ///Create your column list in initstate and use it here
              DataColumn(label: Text('Column Label: 1')),
              DataColumn(label: Text('Column Label: 2')),
            ],
            rows: myDataRowList,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
   );


Hello
All these comments are valid, but the table initially should be empty.
That's typically the case in a production environment.
Checking the table is empty on the app startup does not make sense b/c the table is empty on the app startup.
We have a column and a row. For a column, we only need a column heading.
I need to understand how to initialize rows b/c the rows will be empty on the app startup.
Another comment: what if we have more than one column, then how do we know what rows belongs to what column?
Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thank You

I believe you have some fixed number of column headers, and rows can be added later to the table, your row data should be map, where key is the column name, and value is the value of that particular row cell, further if you don't want to show an empty table i.e only column headers, you can use check like @jamescardona11 mentioned in his response.
